# Mutual information vs Information Gain

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I always thought that mutual information and information gain refer to the same thing, however looking at Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

I see that Information gain is something completely different and asymmetrical,

what are the differences in practice ? when should I choose one of the other ?

Answer (score 8):

We know that $H(X)$ quantifies the amount of information that each observation of $X$ provides, or, equivalently, the minimal amount of bits that we need to encode $X$ ($L_X \to  H(X)$, where $L_X$ is the optima average codelength - first Shannon theorem)

The mutual information 
$$I(X;Y)=H(X) - H(X \mid Y)$$
measures  the reduction in uncertainity (or the "information gained") for $X$ when $Y$ is known.

It can be written as $$I(X;Y)=D(p_{X,Y}\mid \mid p_X \,p_Y)=D(p_{X\mid Y} \,p_Y \mid \mid p_X \,p_Y)$$
wher $D(\cdot)$ is the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) or distance, or relative entropy... or information gain (this later term is not so much used in information theory, in  my experience).

So, they are the same thing. Granted, $D(\cdot)$ is not symmetric in  its arguments, but don't let confuse you. We are *not* computing $D(p_X \mid \mid p_Y)$, but $D(p_X \,p_Y\mid \mid p_{X,Y})$, and this is symmetric in $X,Y$.

A slightly different situation (to connect with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Kullback.E2.80.93Leibler_divergence_and_Bayesian_updating)) arises when one is interested in the effect of knowing a particular value of $Y=y$ . In this case, 
because we are not averaging on $y$, the amount of bits gained [*] would be $  D(p_{X\mid Y} \mid \mid p_X )$... which depends in $y$.

[*] To be precise, that's actually the amount of bits we waste when coding the conditioned source $X\mid Y=y$ as if we didn't knew $Y$ (using the unconditioned distribution of $X$)

Comment: Often for something to be a distance I think it should be symmetric. That could be the reason to call it divergence instead.

Comment: @mathreadler  Yes, that's mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Relation_to_metrics

Comment: So the answer is...they are the same?